# Big-Oh proof feedback

Tags: algorithm

I'm currently reading about Big-Oh and the way to prove the statements.

However, I need a feedback or just direction for proving.

So, I want to prove that for all real numbers a and b,

if b > a and a > 1, then b^n not in O(a^n).

I want to prove by contradiction, since b>a. Let b^n be in O(a^n), then

by definition of Big-oh, there is a constant c and natural number n0, such

that b^n <= ca^n, for all n >= n0. Thus n > max(n0, c) which is

contradiction.

I'm little bit lost and my last sentence, and looking for some feedback if it's possible.

Comment: Seems with Big(O), we are more concerned with the exponent degree than the mantissa.  I would postulate that O(a^2) is the same as O(b^2) for purposes of examining performance (O squared).  Even for O(a) or O(b) - both of these are O(n) - linear run time.

Comment: Thanks, but how this really changing the question? I mean in-order to b^2 be in a^2, there should be some c such that ca^2 >= b^2. Since n=2, n>n0=1.

Comment: And at that point, this is not a computer science / programming problem, but something that might want to migrate over to Math Exchange.  I gave a computer science answer for you.  For me Big(O) means - algorithm complexity.  Higher exponent degree == bad.  Factorial or other degrees == jokingly bad.  O(1)  == ideal.  Others may disagree or have different answers, but I wanted to give you something before your question was closed off topic.

Comment: I see, thanks! I'm little bit confused with such questions, but at least I have now a place to start.

Answer (score 1):

The conclusion follows pretty closely from the definitions you've given, so the proof is not much more than you're already written.  You need to get:

**b^n ∈ O(a^n) ⇒ ∃ c,n0 : (b/a)^n < c for all n > n0**

and

**b > a > 1 ⇒  (b/a) > 1**, and **(b/a)^n** grows without bound.

If you actually want to construct a contradiction you can show that for any **c > 0**, you can choose **n > log(c) / log(b/a)**

Comment: Thanks! I made it through log's, but your first option is really better than my mess with log's.